# cant route to child in pages angular 4

Tags: angular

I'm following the angular routing & navigation example. But my page shows up as file not found when I route. Now when I go to profile page at profile.component.html I see my columns but I don't see anything from `UserComponent`

app/profile/profile.component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="some-columns">
  hi
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

currently in app/profile/profile.module.ts

```
const profileRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/user',
        pathMatch: 'full' 
    },
    {
        path: 'user',
        component: UserComponent,
        children:[
            {
                path:'',
                redirectTo: 'album',
                pathMatch: 'full' 
            },
            {
                path:'album',
                component: AlbumComponent 
            }
        ]
    },
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      profileRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true } 
    )
  ]
})
```

in my app.routing.ts I didn't include the children page but even if I did, it still is the same.

```
const routes: Routes =[{ path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, data: {title: 'Profile'}},]
```

in app.component.ts
I import `imports: [ProfileModule]`

Answer (score 0):

As per the question I understand that you have a profile module on the following route:

myapp.com/profile

when it is accessed as per your routes it should redirect to:

myapp.com/profile/user

the next thing that your routes indicate is that the first child of user is an empty path so it should load by default when user is loaded. That path is also a redirect so the final path should end up like this:

myapp.com/profile/user/album

I would suggest to remove the children of user component then check.

Comment: doesn't do anything... still blank